# The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly This environment variable is needed to run this program

Tags: maven

When I am running the command mvn -version in command prompt I am getting the following error:
The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly
This environment variable is needed to run this program
NB: JAVA_HOME should point to a JDK not a JRE

Please help me out why it is saying this.
I have added JDK 11 in my Environment till Bin path

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4FPtM.png)

Comment: What is the output from `echo %JAVA_HOME%`?

Comment: I got C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10\bin; when running that script

Answer (score 5):

Normally `JAVA_HOME` does **not** contain the `\bin` part of the path.

Your `JAVA_HOME` should be set to something like `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.10`, and your `PATH` should include something like `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.

Comment: Just done what you suggested in my .bashrc and worked, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Please note:

- it is not a good practice when JAVA_HOME contains spaces. This always causes strange effects with the shell scruits.
- it should refer to the directory where the JDK is deployed
- it must not include the `bin` directory.

I always set it to the 8.3-formatted name `progra~1` of the "Program Files" directory. For example:

`JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\`

Find the actual 8.3 name running:  `dir c:\ /x`

Answer (score 0):

JAVA_HOME must not have ";"

If JAVA_HOME be set to something like "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333;**"
It will report an error
"The JAVA_HOME environment variable is not defined correctly,
this environment variable is needed to run this program."

JAVA_HOME should be set to something like "**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_333**"

Answer (score 0):

In my own case, I had two JDK's on my machine (18.1.1 & 19).
JDK 18.1.1 was the active path on the JAVA_HOME.
So, it made my JAVA_HOME looked like this.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk 18.1.1.
Then, I just decided to change it to the highest version.
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19...

Boom!!! it worked....
You can try it out.
I hope it helps.